# How to make eager loading properly?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have an asp net mvc project .
My situation : two tables with one similar column , and  i need display first table and change one value from first table to connected value from the second table.
I tried to make it through the EF Eager Loading, but i have an error

```
SqlException: invalid column name "ReqLpu_Id".
```

I know that i can make join select to one model , but i wan't to understand EF eager loading . Similar column is `STATUS` in ReqLpu Model and `Id` in ReqStatusMo Model

Main Model :

```
public class ReqLpu
    {
        [Key]
        public int IdLpu { get; set; }
        public string COD { get; set; }
        public string M_NAMES { get; set; }
        public string TEL { get; set; }
        public string FAX { get; set; }
        public string E_MAIL { get; set; }
        public int? STATUS { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<ReqStatusMO> ReqStatusMO { get; set; }

    }
```

Second Model:

```
 public class ReqStatusMO
    { 
        [Key]
        public int IdStat { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        ReqLpu ReqLpu { get; set; }
    }
```

Controller:

```
   lpuv = wk.ReqLpus.Include(p => p.ReqStatusMO).ToList();
 return View(lpuv);
```

View:

```
@model IEnumerable<LpuList.Models.ReqLpu>
...
    <table class="table">
            <tr>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.M_NAMES)
                </th>
               ...
            </tr>

            @foreach (var item in Model)
            {
            <tr>
                @Html.HiddenFor(modelItem => item.Id)
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.M_NAMES)
                </td>
              ...
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ReqStatusMO.Select(x=>x.Name))
                </td>
                <td>
    ...
```

Model Binder:

```
 public class WorksContext :DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<ReqLpu> ReqLpus { get; set; }
        public DbSet<ReqStatusMO> ReqStatusMOs { get; set; }
        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<ReqLpu>().ToTable("ReqLpu");
            modelBuilder.Entity<ReqStatusMO>().ToTable("ReqStatusMO");
            modelBuilder.Entity<ReqStatusMO>().HasRequired(x => x.ReqLpu).WithMany(x => x.ReqStatusMO).HasForeignKey(x => x.STATUS);
        }
```

Comment: `ReqLpu_Id` is the EF conventional name of the FK column in the `ReqStatusMO` database table. How is your actual database table column called?

Comment: @IvanStoev STATUS in ReqLpu and  Id in ReqStatusMO .

Comment: This is not an include problem, your FK mapping simply is wrong. Use modelBuilder.Entity<ReqStatusMO>().HasRequired(x=>x.ReqLpu).WithMany(x=>x.ReqStatusMO).HasForeignKey(x=>x.STATUS); to adjust the FK mapping.

Comment: @DevilSuichiro i have error at this 
 'ICollection<ReqLpu>' does not contain a definition for 'ReqStatusMO' and no extension method 'ReqStatusMO' accepting a first argument of type 'ICollection<ReqLpu>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: What does your OnModelCreating() method look like now?

Comment: @DevilSuichiro I updates Question and add OnModelCreating() method in the end

Comment: which line is throwing this exception? Also, I noticed status is nullable, so it should be .HasOptional instead of .HasRequired

Comment: @DevilSuichiro .WithMany(x => x.ReqStatusMO) .   'ICollection<ReqLpu>' does not contain a definition for 'ReqStatusMO' and no extension method 'ReqStatusMO' accepting a first argument of type 'ICollection<ReqLpu>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: Status is not nullable , it was a mistake , now it is   int STATUS

Comment: Can you try exposing the property ReqLpu by making it public? It makes little sense this would result in this error message, but I can't think of any other error source at this point.